# jQuery .live() and .bind() not getting triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a simple chat script, everything is ok, but when I click the button to send message it's not working.

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input id="sendChat" type="text" class="form-control input-sm noborder" placeholder="Treść wiadomości">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button id="ChatButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm noborder">Wyślij</button>
    </span>
</div>
```

**jQUERY CODE:**

```
$('#ChatButton').live('click',function(){
            newComment($('#chatSend').val().trim());
        })

        /* DODANIE KOMENTARZA PO NACIŚNIĘCIU ENTERA */
        $('#sendChat').bind('keypress', function(e) {
            if(e.keyCode==13 && !$('#ChatButton').attr('disabled')){
                newComment($('#sendChat').val().trim());
            }
        });
```

Comment: Could be because `live()` was deprecated and removed from jQuery five years ago ?

Comment: And I don't think bind is that up to date too. Replace both live and bind with 'on' and try again

Comment: Wow, it's the effect of rewriting! Thank you! :) Do you know why now the console are printing "cannot read property 'trim' of undefined(...)"?

Comment: Okay, the error disappeared :) Thank you very much and have a good day!